# Counting when values first appear in one Column and are blank in the previous two Columns

Tags: excel, cells, counting

What would be the formula if I want to count any cells that have a value in e.g. Column C, but are blank in the adjacent cells in Columns A and B? Basically, I want to count when a value first appears in Column C and the adjacent cells in Column B and A are blank. Thanks!

Comment: If there is a formula that allows me to count a range of cells, that'll be great. If not, it can be for just one row at a time. E.g. Count if a value appears in C3 but not in A3 or B3.

Comment: When I compared just two cells from two separte columns I used: =COUNTIFS(C3,">0",B3,"") but now I would like to count if a value appears in Column C but not in Column A or B (E.g. C3 vs A3 and B3.

Answer (score 0):

Try COUNTIFS like this to count all rows that meet your conditions

`=COUNTIFS(C:C,"<>",B:B,"",A:A,"")`